# Running a 3D printer, LED strip, and fan from a 24V PSU

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led, switches, 24v

I am working on a project to design an enclosure for my 3D printer. The enclosure is designed, but I am looking for some guidance/suggestions on the electrical side. I plan to add a few strips of 24V LEDs above the printer for lighting, and an external 12V centrifugal fan that will be used to filter air. My goal is to remove the PSU from the printer and mount it outside the enclosure to improve cooling (currently it faces the table top in an unenclosed environment. Second I want to add three DC switches that allow me to toggle power to the printer, the LED lights, and the fan. I have attached a diagram showing how I plan to wire everything. I want to use the current main switch from the printer to control power from the wall (AC) to the PSU. From there I would like to be able to route the 24V outputs (of which there are three) from the PSU through each of the switches so I can turn on the printer, the LEDs, and the 12V fan independently of each other if needed. For the fan I have a buck converter to step down the voltage to 12V.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this as simple as just finding three switches that can handle 24V and a high enough amperage (20A to be safe) and wiring them up as described/shown?
2. Are there any obvious (not to me) issues that I am not seeing?
3. Are there any suggestions for an appropriate switch to use, I am having trouble finding a suitable 24V switch (probably because I am unfamiliar with where to look).

Any and all advice/feedback is appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Update 2023-09-30:

After looking into this a bit more I am starting to rethink how I'd like to set up this circuit. My plan as of now is to use smaller, 24V switches with a lower current rating and use the first switch (which I will call the primary) to switch on a relay to pass the higher current power to the printer. I will add a fuse (15 A) between the PSU and the relay for protection. The questions I have about this approach are as follows:

1. Will the relay I have selected work for this application ([BOSCH 0332019203 High capacity relay](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/728705/Bosch/0332019203/1))? Meaning will it be able to handle the sustained load of the printer running for hours on end (sometimes 24 hrs. or more). I believe it should based on the spec sheet but I am no expert at reading those documents.
2. Is there a better way to achieve my goal to control the printer and peripherals? Should I consider a solid state relay or other device?

I have attached my new diagram and a screenshot of the relevant relay specs in case the link doesn't work.

[image: Revise wiring diagram]

[image: Relevant relay specs]

Comment: What is this current "AC INPUT W/SWITCH"?  Is it a box with a switch on it?  What is its current rating?

Comment: It is a power socket with a switch. Current rating is 10A @ 250V. The Model number for the switch is AC-14-F1.

Comment: What is the current draw of the printer and the LEDs?

Comment: Printer Current is unknown. The specs from the manual simply states "Power Input: 110V/220V AC, 50/60 Hz" and a Rated power of "400W". LEDs Current will depend on length chosen But my upper bound for that is 2A. The Fan current draw is 1 Amp.

Comment: 16.7A at 24V is 400W, so you will need a different or additional power supply to run an additional 60W of accessories at the same time.

Comment: Isn't that assuming that the printer requires all 400W of power? The power supply is a 400W supply but that is fairly common among budget 3D printer. In the 3D print community it's not uncommon to run accessories of the stock power supply. It's true I don't know what the true power draw of my printer is but I do doubt it uses the full out of the supply. It's also the power and current draw vary as parameter of the printer change as well.

Comment: The printer's manual says 400W; you are free to make whichever assumptions you like about how conservative that figure is.  Do I think your power supply will burst into flames?  Probably not, though I have seen power supplies melt internal traces at 75% of nameplate current, and you are planning to overload it by 15%.  More likely if there is an issue, you will see either voltage sag or overcurrent protection engage, both of which will cause your printer to stop and your print to fail.

Comment: Your point is well taken and I may end up getting an alternative 24V supply with a higher wattage rating. Beyond that, will what I have in the diagram work? Assuming I have sufficiently rated switches will my design work as intended (from a hypothetical standpoint)? Are there components I am missing?

Comment: Your wiring diagram is correct; you shouldn't need any other components.  When looking for switches, make sure you use the DC amps rating and not the AC amps rating which can be much higher since AC current is easier to break (it drops to zero twice per cycle).  And of course, you can always use a higher switch current and voltage rating than you need.  20A might be a bit overkill unless you like how the switch looks or it's a good deal.  You can also get a small (~75-100W) 24V supply and wire it up to the AC input in parallel with the existing DC converter.  The 400W one will draw <4A as is.

Comment: Great. Thank for the help, this has been very informative and it is much appreciated!

Comment: A 20A wall switch for $0.50 from the box store should work, even on DC, and while it's 100% safe, it _if_ does wear out early (compared to switching AC), you can still buy several for the price of a "legit" 20A DC switch.